# Magento2 Multiples fileds for the AbstractModel

Tags: magento2, collection

How can I add more than one field in the load method of the \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel

```
$consumptionCollection = $this->_consumptionFactory->create()->load($iccid, 'iccid');
```

I want to filter the model collection for more than one field

Comment: You want to filter collection or  model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following sample there I am filtering by 2 fields from the database:
field1 and field2

```
$consumptionCollection = $this->_consumptionFactory->create();
$consumptionCollection->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('field1', array('eq' => 'value1'))
->addFieldToFilter('field2', array('eq' => 'value2'))
->load();
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like this:

```
$consumptionCollection = $this->_consumptionFactory->create();
$consumptionCollection->addFieldToFilter(
                            'filter1',
                            array(
                                'eq' => $var1)
                        )
                        ->addFieldToFilter(
                            'filter2',
                            array('eq' => $var2)
                        );
$consumptionCollection->load();
```

Comment: I can't find the addFieldToFilter method.  And give me an invalid method error if i use it

Comment: What is the `_consumptionFactory` type?